# jquery post form with multiple same name field

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I have a biling form with same input in (td) on each line (tr).
Now I want to submit this form with full filled lines only.

I read some article on your site  but I can't submit my form.

Here is the html code:

```
<div id="fac_table">
    <table id="matable" width="100%">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th width="10px">
                    <img id="insArticle" src='../../images/icon_add.png' width='16' height='16'>
                </th>
                <th width="250px">
                    Désignation
                </th>
                <th width="30">
                    Unité
                </th>
                <th width="30">
                    Quantité
                </th>
                <th width="30">
                    Prix
                </th>
                <th width="30">
                    TVA
                </th>
                <th width="30">
                    Total
                </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="10px">
                    <img id="insArticle" src='../../images/icon_add.png' width='16' height='16'>
                </td>
                <td width="250px">
                    <input name="designation" type="text" class="facBig" />
                </td>
                <td width="30">
                    <input name="unite" type="text" class="facSmall" />
                </td>
                <td width="30">
                    <input name="quantite" type="text" class="facSmall" />
                </td>
                <td width="30">
                    <input name="prixUnite" type="text" class="facSmall" value="" />
                </td>
                <td width="30">
                    <input name="taxe" type="text" class="facSmall" value="" />
                </td>
                <td width="30">
                    <input name="totLine" type="text" class="facSmall" value="" />
                </td>
            </tr>
              <tr>
                <td width="10px">
                    <img id="insArticle" src='../../images/icon_add.png' width='16' height='16'>
                </td>
                <td width="250px">
                    <input name="designation" type="text" class="facBig" />
                </td>
                <td width="30">
                    <input name="unite" type="text" class="facSmall" />
                </td>
                <td width="30">
                    <input name="quantite" type="text" class="facSmall" />
                </td>
                <td width="30">
                    <input name="prixUnite" type="text" class="facSmall" value="" />
                </td>
                <td width="30">
                    <input name="taxe" type="text" class="facSmall" value="" />
                </td>
                <td width="30">
                    <input name="totLine" type="text" class="facSmall" value="" />
                </td>
            </tr> <tr>
                <td width="10px">
                    <img id="insArticle" src='../../images/icon_add.png' width='16' height='16'>
                </td>
                <td width="250px">
                    <input name="designation" type="text" class="facBig" />
                </td>
                <td width="30">
                    <input name="unite" type="text" class="facSmall" />
                </td>
                <td width="30">
                    <input name="quantite" type="text" class="facSmall" />
                </td>
                <td width="30">
                    <input name="prixUnite" type="text" class="facSmall" value="" />
                </td>
                <td width="30">
                    <input name="taxe" type="text" class="facSmall" value="" />
                </td>
                <td width="30">
                    <input name="totLine" type="text" class="facSmall" value="" />
                </td>
            </tr> <tr>
                <td width="10px">
                    <img id="insArticle" src='../../images/icon_add.png' width='16' height='16'>
                </td>
                <td width="250px">
                    <input name="designation" type="text" class="facBig" />
                </td>
                <td width="30">
                    <input name="unite" type="text" class="facSmall" />
                </td>
                <td width="30">
                    <input name="quantite" type="text" class="facSmall" />
                </td>
                <td width="30">
                    <input name="prixUnite" type="text" class="facSmall" value="" />
                </td>
                <td width="30">
                    <input name="taxe" type="text" class="facSmall" value="" />
                </td>
                <td width="30">
                    <input name="totLine" type="text" class="facSmall" value="" />
                </td>
            </tr> <tr>
                <td width="10px">
                    <img id="insArticle" src='../../images/icon_add.png' width='16' height='16'>
                </td>
                <td width="250px">
                    <input name="designation" type="text" class="facBig" />
                </td>
                <td width="30">
                    <input name="unite" type="text" class="facSmall" />
                </td>
                <td width="30">
                    <input name="quantite" type="text" class="facSmall" />
                </td>
                <td width="30">
                    <input name="prixUnite" type="text" class="facSmall" value="" />
                </td>
                <td width="30">
                    <input name="taxe" type="text" class="facSmall" value="" />
                </td>
                <td width="30">
                    <input name="totLine" type="text" class="facSmall" value="" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

and here is the jquery code:

```
$("#facform").submit(function()
{
    var sendURL = $(this).attr("action");
    var sendPost = $(this).attr("method");
    var facArray = $(this).serialize();

    alert(sendURL + "  " + sendPost + "  " + facArray);

    $.ajax(
    {
        type: sendPost,
        url: sendURL,
        data: facArray,
        success: function(response)
        {
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
});
$("#facform").submit();
```

The alert give the correct information, but I've a blank post on my sendfac.php.

Thank you for help.

Comment: Means you want to send separately the value that remains in certain <tr>?

Comment: You forget `method: "POST",`.

Comment: what is the difference between type and method?

Comment: do you  know what is method of your form. is it post or get ? also please remove your answer and tell that in comment..

Comment: OK after adding the bracketts, I made some new tests and, all lines dynamically added dont be present in POST.

I think the Post I can see on my exec page is the normal post of my form. Could you please tell me how can I POST all Hardcoded lines + dynamically inserted lines without unfilled lines.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Add this code. You forgot to add your method.

```
 $.ajax(
{
    method: sendPost , 
    url: sendURL,
    data: facArray,
    success: function(response)
    {
        console.log(response);
    }
});
```

Or try with this code

```
$.post("/"+sendURL, { data: facArray}, function success (data) {
                alert("Done");
            }, "json");
```

Comment: Did you tested with the second one?\

Comment: [Let us Continue discussion through Chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92650/jquery)

Comment: Sorry but it seems that i can't use chat room

Answer (score -1):

You should add brackets to form fields names. Because you are trying to send array of values.

Like this: `<input name="designation[]" type="text" class="facBig" />`

Comment: or if you obtain your table using a cicle you can add a counter

Comment: Hello,thank you for your answer, I tried with braket but i've some other script that not respond with the bracket like this one. var designation = $(this).parent().find("td [name=designation]"); How can i add bracket to this

Comment: I think you want to use this ...find('input[name="designation[]"]');

Comment: Thank you all for help, with bracket all is fine now, now there is a way to delete from array all lines that have nothing or totLine to 0.00?

Comment: Are you handling data with PHP? If yes, you can use PHP function [array_filter](http://php.net/array_filter) to crawl each form value and remove unnecessary.

Comment: After a complete review of my page, the problem was in the HTML form and the position of the open form and close form, now I can try to use the post datas...

Thank you all for help